# PDF of a new random variable from given random variable.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

I was given a PDF of a random variable $X$
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
    \frac{1}{x\sqrt{2\pi}}\ e^{\frac{-(\log(x))^2}{2}}\ ,& \text{if } x>0\\
    0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Then the author has defined a new random variable $X_{\varepsilon}, \varepsilon \leq 1$ and write a new PDF

$$f_{\varepsilon}(x) = f(x)[1+\varepsilon \sin{(2\pi\ \log(x)})],\ x \in \mathbb{R}.\ \ \ \text{eq(1)}$$

I have shown that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x) \sin{(2\pi\ \log(x)}) dx = 0.$

Can we always do a similar step performed in eq(1) step for every PDF or is it just specific to this family of PDF?

Note: The question was related to the MGFs.

Comment: You can always define a new random variable by taking the PDF of an old variable and "doing something to it" as long as you keep the new function positive and it's integral 1. This transformation has these two properties, so it's fine.

Comment: If you use \log instead of log and \varepsilon instead of \epsilon, it looks much nicer

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, it seems like that result (Eq. 1), is essentially a statement about transforming from one random variable to another using the change of variables method.

Quoting from Wikipedia (Additional details here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Function_of_random_variables_and_change_of_variables_in_the_probability_density_function):

"This follows from the fact that the probability contained in a differential area must be invariant under change of variables. That is,

$$\left| f_Y(y)\, dy \right| = \left| f_X(x)\, dx \right|$$"

I hope this helps.